# For Statement in assigning random values to integers in VBA

Tags: vba

```
NN1 = Int((500 - 100 + 1) * Rnd + 100)
NN2 = Int((500 - 100 + 1) * Rnd + 100)
NN3 = Int((500 - 100 + 1) * Rnd + 100)
NN4 = Int((500 - 100 + 1) * Rnd + 100)
```

I assume that we can reduce this into

```
For i = 1 to 4
"NN" & i = Int((500 - 100 + 1) * Rnd + 100)
Next i
```

However, I am getting a compilation error. How do I rectify this?

Comment: Use a `Dictionary` or `Collection`. `"NN" & i` is not equivalent to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim NN() As Integer
For i = 1 To 4
NN(i) = Int((500 - 100 + 1) * Rnd + 100)
Next i
```

I would suggest using an Array instead of multiple Integers